# Unable to locate package blind9

Tags: package-management

When I try to install Blind9 package in Ubuntu server, I am getting error:

```
Unable to locate package blind9
```

How can resolve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure the package is called `blind9`? A quick Google search suggests that maybe you actually want `bind9`.

Answer (score 0):

The package you're looking for is certainly **bind9** not bLind9.

```
sudo apt-get install bind9
```